# Can I get Code Contracts to warn me about "illegal" subtyping?

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, code-contracts, invariants, subtyping

Sorry if this question seems too long. Before I can ask it, I need to show where it's coming from.

### Set-up:

Given the following immutable type `Rectangle`:

```
class Rectangle
{
    public Rectangle(double width, double height) { … }

    public double Width  { get { … } }
    public double Height { get { … } }
}
```

… it seems perfectly legal to derive a type `Square` from it:

```
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

class Square : Rectangle
{
    public Square(double sideLength) : base(sideLength, sideLength) { }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    void WidthAndHeightAreAlwaysEqual()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(Width == Height);
    }
}
```

… because the derived class can make sure that its own invariant isn't ever violated.

But as soon as I make `Rectangle` mutable:

```
class Rectangle
{
    public double Width  { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    …
}
```

… I should no longer derive `Square` from it, because `Square` shouldn't ever have independent setters for `Width` and `Height`.

### Question:

What can I do with Code Contracts such that it will warn me of a contract violation as soon as I derive `Square` from the mutable `Rectangle` class? Preferably, Code Contracts' static analysis would already give me a warning at compile-time.

In other words, my goal is to encode the following rules with Code Contracts:

- `Width` and `Height` of a `Rectangle` may be changed independently from one another.
- `Width` and `Height` of a `Square` cannot be changed independently from one another, and that wouldn't be meaningful in the first place.

… and do it in such a way that Code Contracts will notice whenever these rules "collide".

### What I've considered so far:

**1. Adding an invariant to `Rectangle`:**

```
class Rectangle
{
    …
    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    void WidthAndHeightAreIndependentFromOneAnother()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(Width != Height || Width == Height);
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that while the invariant correctly states, "Width and Height don't have to be equal, but they can be", it is ineffectual, (1) because it is a tautology, and (2) because it is less restrictive than the invariant `Width == Height` in the derived class `Square`. Perhaps it's even optimised away by the compiler before Code Contracts ever sees it.

**2. Adding post-conditions to `Rectangle`'s setters:**

```
public double Width
{
    get { … }
    set { Contract.Ensures(Height == Contract.OldValue(Height)); … }
}

public double Height
{
    get { … }
    set { Contract.Ensures(Width == Contract.OldValue(Width)); … }
}
```

This will forbid the derived class `Square` from simply updating `Height` to `Width` whenever `Width` is changed and vice versa, it won't stop me *per se* from deriving a `Square` class from `Rectangle`. But that's my goal: getting Code Contracts to warn me that `Square` must not be derived from a mutable `Rectangle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BrokenGlass and @Mathias for the link to the recent MSDN Magazine article named [***Code Contracts: Inheritance and the Liskov Principle***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288081.aspx). While I believe there's something wrong in it (I'll get to that in a second… see the second part of this answer), it's helped me decide on a solution.

### Solution I've decided on:

1. I'm adding the following post-conditions to the base class `Rectangle`:

   ```
   public double Width
   {
       set { Contract.Ensures(Height == Contract.OldValue(Height)); }
   }

   public double Height
   {
       set { Contract.Ensures(Width == Contract.OldValue(Width)); }
   }
   ```

   These basically assert that `Width` and `Height` can be set independently from one another.
2. One invariant is added in the derived class `Square`:

   ```
   Contract.Invariant(Width == Height);
   ```

   This basically states just the opposite.

Taken together, these will *eventually* result in a contract violation — admittedly not at compile-time, but it seems that could only be done with Code Contracts in certain corner cases (namely, when a derived class starts adding pre-conditions.)

### Why is the solution in the MSDN Magazine article not helpful?

The MSDN article seemingly shows a solution that has the advantage of compile-time warnings. Why do I stick with the above solution that doesn't have this bonus?

**Short answer:**

An unexplained change in the code examples makes it clear that the article sets up an artificial situation in order to show off Code Contracts' static analysis.

**Long answer:**

The article starts off with a code example (→ Figure 1) of a `Rectangle` class with individual setters for both `Width` and `Height`. The next time that the `Rectangle` class is shown (→ Figure 2), the setters have been made `private` and are only used through an added method `SetSize(width, height)`.

The article does not say explain why this change was silently introduced. In fact, that change would probably not make any sense at all in the context of `Rectangle` alone, unless of course you already knew that you would derive a class like `Square` where you need to add a pre-condition `width == height`. You couldn't add this as a pre-condition when the setters for `Width` and `Height` are separated from one another. And if you could not add that pre-condition, you would not get a compile-time warning from Code Contracts.

Answer (score 4):

There was a very relevant article in a recent MSDN magazine discussing basically the same problem: [**"Code Contracts: Inheritance and the Liskov Principle"**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288081.aspx) - I wouldn't be able to come up with a better answer.

What your regard as “illegal” subtyping is basically a violation of the Liskov substitution principle, the article shows how code contracts can help detect this problem.

Comment: A-ha! _"Method 'Square.SetSize' overrides 'Rectangle.SetSize', thus cannot add Requires."_ That's brilliant! Too bad that it requires this artificial refactoring of both `Width`'s and `Height`'s setters into a combined `SetSize` method... I wonder if there's a similar solution with overridden `ContractInvariantMethod`s?

Comment: Maybe I should explain my above comment a little more: Their whole re-design of `Rectangle` such that the two setters are combined into `SetSize` seems constructed to show off Code Contracts: That refactoring does not make sense for `Rectangle` (where independent setters for `Width` and `Height` would make perfect sense). Ostensibly, they did that because they knew that independent setters wouldn't make sense for `Square`. I.e., they refactored `Rectangle` because of `Square`! So they wouldn't actually have needed the compiler warning, because they had already thought about violating the LSP!

Answer (score 2):

There is an article in the [July 2011 issue of MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288081.aspx) which describes pretty much your problem, with the same example, and discusses the use of Code Contracts and the Liskov substitution principle.